# Can't set image from gallery or camera in dialogFragment android

Tags: java, android

I want to show image from gallery or camera using library easy image and  appear it using glide to my dialog Fragment. But the image still can't show. I use butterKnife to bindView my dialogFragment. Here is my some code. Thanks before

````
        EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, getActivity(),
                new DefaultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onImagePicked(File imageFile, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
                        switch (type) {
                            case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
                                Glide.with(context)
                                        .load(imageFile)

                                       .centerCrop()
                                        .into(ivPhotoProfile);
                                ViewUtils.showLog("photo" + ivPhotoProfile);
                                ivPhotoProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                break;
                            case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
                                imageTaken = ImageUtils.compressImage(imageFile,ImageUtils.createPhotoFile(getActivity()));

                                Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
                                        .load(imageTaken)
                                        .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform())
                                        .into(ivPhotoProfile);

                                break;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled(EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {

                    }
                });
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,your DialogFragment does't show your ImageView correctly.pls make sure that your DialogFragment has enough space for your ImageView and showed as expect

Comment: It's not because that fren

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Setting a specific width for the `ImageView` fixed it for me